# How do the sister and brother learn to swim under water?

Tags: plot-explanation, old

In the movie, ***Old***, the sister and brother manage to escape from the beach by swimming under water through coral.

When the movie starts, they are no older than 10 and by the end of the movie, they are in their middle 50s.

We know by staying on the beach, their ageing process accelerate, but skills such as swimming under water for such a long distance is unlikely to be developed naturally, is there any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One plausible explanation I can think of is derived from what was said during the argument the parents had before their trip to the beach.

> Their current vacation would be the last one as a family.

Because of this, I can presume that they have learnt how to swim based on their past experiences. To cement this point further, both kids were already in their swimwear readying for the trip to the beach.

In addition, the coral reef area is relatively close to the water surface, given that there are small pockets to the surface along the way.

Swimming under water close to the surface should not be a major problem to both the brother and the sister.